# Ubuntu crashed, now my disk is not recognized

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I started using Ubuntu a few months ago. It was working well until it crashed, I boot back up, and it booted into windows, and my disk is not recognized in windows, or in BIOS. How can I get my important data back?

(I was dual booting with 2 separate drives)

Comment: Try booting with a bootable USB key and see if the drive can be seen.  The drive may have a hardware issue.

Comment: Ok, when I go into windows disk management, I can see the disk, but it needs to be initialized, so I don't want to format it. I'll try this on an old laptop once I get a chance

Comment: The disk may be OK. The OS crash may have corrupted the disk structure. If the file tables have been corrupted, you may need a recovery agency to recover data.

Comment: What would you recommend to use if the file tables were corrupted?

Comment: First step should be to boot a live USB, for example [systemrescue](https://www.system-rescue.org/) and check the drives S.M.A.R.T. status with `smartctl -a /dev/somedrive` as well as making a backup with `dd`. You can then try to recover the data from the backup, without risking to further damage the data on the disk itself. If there is really valuable data on the drive and you don't have a backup, better pay some big bucks for a professional data recovery, as it is really easy to make it much worse.

Comment: `testdisk` could be able to recover damaged partitions, if it fails you could try to use `photorec` to recover individual files.

Comment: Everyone here is mostly correct but nobody here has pointed out the "elephant in the room".  99% chance you are running a journaling file system (like EXT4) that doesn't allow for this sort of thing to happen.  That gives you a 99% chance that your drive is damaged.  Whatever you do, don't trust it if and when you recover stuff.  Also, if you REALLY care about the drive data, use `dd` or `ddrecover` to copy it to a different drive before attempting to run `testdisk` on the new copied data to recover data.

Comment: One more thing.  If the drive is big. `dd` can take WEEKS to copy an entire drive if it is failing.  You will need a machine dedicated to this task.

Comment: Yes, I really care about the data. I have been building an app with Android Studio, switched to linux, and now I have about a month's work lost.

Comment: Can I have an example of what I need to do with dd to fix this? I am still new to Linux.

Comment: *I really care about the data* No, not really. If you did then you'd have backups of your work files, at least. In  that case the loss of a drive with an OS installed is mostly irrelevant. Any Linux distro can be reinstalled in minutes in a new drive and not nearly as much is needed to then recover the backup. Keep that in mind for the future. Use the 3-2-1 rule: 3 copies in at least 2 different media and 1 off-site (cloud storage, network share, etc.)

Comment: `dd`fixes nothing. It's purpose is to create a 1:1 raw copy of data to a different drive where you can then experiment with the suggested recovery software without fear of loosing it permanently because you'll be working in the copy, not in the original. All it takes is one small mistake/distraction

Comment: I am looking at the SMART tests, and many of the attributes say: Pre-fail, and when I try to run a test, I am getting an input-output error. Is this a big issue?